# Reduction of order issues in Differential Equations problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

(a) Let $u$ be a non-zero solution of the second order equation
$$
y^{''}+P(x)y^{'}+Q(x)y = 0
$$
Show that the substitution $y=uv$ converts the equation
$$
y^{''}+P(x)y^{'}+Q(x)y = R(x)
$$
into a first order linear equation for $v^{'}$.

(b) Obtain a non-zero solution of the equation 
$$
y^{''} - 4y^{'} + x^2(y^{'}-4y) = 0
$$
by inspection and use the method of part(a) to find a solution of
$$
y^{''} - 4y^{'} + x^2(y^{'}-4y) = 2xe^{-x^{3}/3}
$$

I feel I have a solution to part(a) which I approached as follows:

Let $y = uv$ which means $y^{'} = u^{'}v+uv^{'}$ and 
$$
y^{''} = (u^{''}v + u^{'}v^{'}) + (u^{'}v^{'} + uv^{''}) = u^{''}v + uv^{''} +2u^{'}v^{'}
$$
substituting this into the original equation:
$$
y^{''}+P(x)y^{'}+Q(x)y = R(x)
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
(u^{''}v + uv^{''} +2u^{'}v^{'})+P(x)(u^{'}v+uv^{'}) + Q(x)(uv) = R(x)
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
v^{''}(u) + v^{'}(2u^{'}+uP(x))+v(u^{''}+P(x)u^{'}+uQ(x))= R(x)
$$
which (AFAIK) is a first order linear equation for $v^{'}$.

Assuming this approach is correct (which I'm not certain of) I have absolutely no clue as to how to obtain the solution in part(b) by inspection in order to proceed. It also makes me suspect that I have "missed the point" of part (a) as well.

Any suggestions would be useful at this stage.

Comment: Your approach is correct, but it would be more obvious if you would notice that since $u$ is a solution to homogeneous variant of your equation, $v(u'' + P(x)u' + uQ(x)) = 0$ leaving you with a truly first order linear equation for $v'$: $v''u + v'(2u' + uP(x)) = R(x)$, which is much easier to solve (possible in other words) than original. That observation is a point of (a). As to (b) I don't see any obvious solutions but you may want to try $xe^{x^3}$ or something in it's vicinity, can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a solution of 
$$
y'' - 4y' + x^2(y'-4y) = 0,
$$
you can use the fact that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(y'-4y) + x^2 (y'-4y)=0,
$$
from which you can find $y'-4y$ as a function of $x$. Then you solve this first order ODE. Since you only need ONE solution, you can take all the integrating constants to be zero (usually giving you the simplest solution).